# Multiple Versus Multivariate Regression

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-regression

I have 4 IVs and 4 DVs and not sure if I have to use linear regression (one IV and one DV at a time) or multiple regression (the 4 IVs and one DV at a time)?

Is there any application where I can put the 4 IVs and the 4 DVs together and run the analysis?

Comment: If you're interested in multivariate effects, there are many ways to do this. In R you can use manova, in SPSS, multivariate GLM, in SAS, proc glm. You can use a multilevel model or a structural equation model in any of those programs too.

Comment: It would be easier to make a more concrete suggestion if you specified your question more precisely and gave more background information. What kind of subject-matter problem are you solving?